# como usar la variable rand en c++ y que no repitan numero?

Tags: c++

Ayuda estoy haciendo un batalla naval en c++ y tengo que enfrentar ak usuario frente a la maquina  y debo usar la funcion rand para generar un coordenada aleatoria dentro de una matriz 10x10, que hago para que no repita el mismo dato?.

Comment: Tu problema es que distintas ejecuciones del programa te producen la misma secuencia de coordenadas, o que una ejecucion del programa te produce una secuencia con coordenadas repetidas?

Answer (score 5):

Para generar números aleatorios en C++ lo suyo es hacer uso de la librería `random`, disponible desde C++11. Esta librería permite crear números aleatorios usando diferentes juegos de generadores y distribuidores (para repartir estadísticamente la aparición de los diferentes números. Un ejemplo:

```
std::random_device rd; // Proporciona la semilla
std::mt19937 gen(rd()); // Generador aleatorio
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 6); // Distribución uniforme
for(int n=0; n<10; ++n)
    std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
std::cout << '\n';
```

¿Por qué no es recomendable usar `srand(time(NULL))`? Porque es un mecanismo portencialmente inseguro. Es un generador anticuado y *poco aleatorio* que puede dar lugar a problemas de seguridad en nuestra aplicación.

Por otro lado para no repetir números únicamente te queda la posibilidad de almacenar los resultados en un contenedor. En este caso el más adecuado es `set`. Puesto que `set` no admite duplicados se convierte en un buen candidato:

```
std::set<int> datos;

do
{
  std::cout << "Introduce un número: ";
  int numero;
  std::cin >> numero;

  bool ok;

  // opción 1
  // insert retorna un pair.
  // El primer parámetro del pair es un booleano que indica si se ha hecho la
  // inserción y el segundo es un iterador al elemento.
  // tie es una función que permite extraer los elementos del pair y solo nos
  // quedamos con el primero, el segundo lo descartamos con std::ignore.
  std::tie(ok,std::ignore) = datos.insert(numero);

  // opción 2
  // primero comprobamos si ya existe el número y después lo insertamos
  // 
  ok = (datos.count(numero) == 0);
  datos.insert(numero);

  if( !ok )
    std::cout << "Número repetido" << std::endl;
} while( datos.size() < 10 );
```

Otra posible solución pasa por generar un vector con todas las posibilidades, que en tu caso imagino que serán 100 posibilidades. Después desordenas dicho vector para, finalmente, ir sacando elementos uno a uno (por el principio o el final). Al estar el vector desordenado irás obteniendo casillas aleatorias y sin repeticiones:

```
std::vector<int> datos(10);

// Rellenamos datos con números del 1 al 10
std::iota(std::begin(datos), std::end(datos), 1); 

std::cout << "Array ordenado: " << std::endl;  
for( auto i : datos )
  std::cout << i << " ";
std::cout << std::endl;

// mezclamos el array
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 g(rd());

std::shuffle(datos.begin(), datos.end(), g);

std::cout << "Array desordenado: " << std::endl;  
for( auto i : datos )
  std::cout << i << " ";
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Un saludo.

Comment: La respuesta es excelente mas creo que le falta un detalle educativo que [jc_delgado](http://es.stackoverflow.com/users/5200/jc-delgado) podría apreciar ya que lo considero necesario para mejorar su conocimiento de RNG: Sería interesante explicar en qué consiste una distribución aleatoria uniforme y por qué es interesante en su problema.

Por otro lado, añado que `std::rand` es uniforme en el rango `INT_MAX`, pese a ser impopular es muy ligero y con un uso directo y fácil para estudiantes, pero [se ha propuesto deprecarlo](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3775.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Para que no te genere el mismo numero, tenes que cambiar la semilla con la que se genera ese numero, la forma mas facil es usar el tiempo actual.

con srand vas cambiando la semilla.
Agrega

```
srand (time(NULL));
```

antes del rand() y vas a tener tus numeros aleatorios.

Comment: Tal y como lo pintas parece que hay que llamar a `srand` antes de pedir cada número aleatorio cuando únicamente sería necesario hacerlo una vez antes de empezar a pedir números.

Comment: Esta respuesta es pertinente si se aclara que solo debe llamarse srand al comienzo del programa, y si de lo que se trata es de evitar que distintas ejecuciones del programa devuelvan la _misma secuencia_ de números. Si de lo que se trata, en cambio es de evitar que en la secuencia (dentro una ejecucion) haya numeros repetidos (como parece), esta respuesta es irrelevante.

Comment: Gracias por el consejo. Como pregunto, parecía que el problema era que rand() le tiraba siempre el mismo valor, por eso di esa solución tan básica.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta propuesta por @ReymonARG no es correcta puesto que no garantiza que los números generados no se repitan. Lo mas sencillo es guardar una matriz auxiliar de tipo bool en la que guardes que posiciones son validas y si se vuelve a generar un dato ya existente descartarlo.

Otra opción es generar un vector con todas las posiciones posibles y mezclarlo con la función [random_shuffle](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/) de la librería `algorithm`.

Comment: Entiendo que el op está utilizando una sola semilla, y por eso repite el mismo dato. En ese caso, la respuesta de @ReymonARG es correcta. Pero también es correcto tu análisis de almacenar los números generados para evitar volver a utilizarlos.

Comment: Un inciso... `random_shuffle` está marcada como *deprecated* en el estándar C++11 y desaparecida en C++14. Yo no propondría esta solución bajo ninguna circunstancia.