# ¿Por qué el número que me genera el rand() siempre es el mismo?

Tags: c++

Estoy usando la librería stdlib de c++ para generar un número aleatorio con la función rand() pero resulta que cada vez que compilo me sale 41:

```
#include <iostream>   
#include <stdlib.h>   
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int a = rand();
    cout<<a<<endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Estoy aprendiendo C++ ahora y no sé que hago mal.

Comment: Fijate en esta pregunta creo que ya han tenido antes ese problema:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/14421/como-usar-la-variable-rand-en-c-y-que-no-repitan-numero Básicamente se aconseja utilizar `set` pues no admite duplicados. Espero que te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, se te agradece, pero esa pregunta fue cerrada, saludos.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

El error es que nunca inicias la **semilla del randon** lo cual debes de hacer con

```
srand(time(NULL));// que es lo mas comun, tomar el tiempo.
```

Posterior a eso tu puedes llamar a `rand()` y obtener diferentes valores.

```
#include <iostream>   
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>//en c++
using namespace std;

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int a = rand();
    cout<<a<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Intenta con ese codigo, no lo compile pero estoy seguro que funcionara.

Ademas creo que `rand()` retorna un numero entre 0 - 1 y este es un `double`, asi  que debes de tener cuidado con eso.

Comment: Hola Shassain, tu siempre tan atento. El programa siempre me retorna 41. ¿Qué es eso de iniciar la semilla del random? ¿Algún link donde pueda entender mejor eso?

Comment: pues los numeros random se generan atravez de algoritmos de los cuales existen varios, y podria decirse que en todos(no estoy seguro de eso) es necesario una semilla(solo es una variable) para generar numeros random, puedes buscar en google sobre ellos solo busca **algoritmos para numeros random**

Comment: el error del 41 sigue?¿

Comment: Ya arreglé el error. Solo que tuve que agregarle a tu código la librería time. Saludos

Comment: ah si tienes razon, son cosas que olvidas cuando ya llevas tiempo sin manejar el lenguaje jeje.

Comment: No añadas `<ctime>` y `<time.h>`, o una u otra, nunca ambas. El programa es C++ así que en caso de elegir una, deberá ser `<ctime>`. Y `<stdlib.h>` debería ser `<cstdlib>`.

Answer (score 4):

La respuesta de [Shassain](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/148665/2742), pese a ser válida no menciona partes importantes de la generación de números aleatorios.

#### Se desaconsjea el uso de `std::rand`.

El algoritmo de `std::rand` no forma parte de la especificación de C++ y en consecuencia puede no ser portable con resultados y rendimiento cuestionables, el algoritmo de generación puede variar entre implementaciones y deja poco o ningún control al programador. Por este y otros motivos [se está estudiando deprecarlo](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3924.pdf).

La librería estándar de C++ ofrece [utilidades estándar de generación de números pseudo-aleatorios](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) desde 2011. Estas nuevas utilidades premiten al programador controlar tanto el algoritmo de generación como la distribución.

#### Propuesta.

Teniendo en cuenta lo anterior, si usas la cabecera `<random>` de C++11 tu código podría quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
// No se incluye ninguna cabecera de C

int main()
{
    // La cláusula using sólo afecta a main
    using namespace std;

    // Tenemos control sobre el algoritmo y distribución a usar.
    random_device device;
    // Se usa el algoritmo Mersenne twister
    // https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister
    mt19937 generador(device());
    // Escogemos una distribucion uniforme entre 0 y 100
    uniform_int_distribution<> distribucion(0, 100);

    /* Generamos un número pseudo-aleatorio con el algoritmo
    mt19937 distribuido uniformemente entre 0 y 100 */
    int a = distribucion(generador);

    // No usamos endl.
    cout << a << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

El código anterior ya genera números aleatorios (en el rango indicado) que varían en cada ejecución sin necesidad de imbuir una semilla.